# Is it fundamentally possible to prove a current industry standard end-to-end system of secure data storage and transfer?

Tags: storage

I know we can design an ultra simple system that is proven to perform one thing with perfect security. We've done that. That's called a *proven system*, and it has been done with micro-kernels. (An example of such a system is [sel4](https://sel4.systems/Info/Docs/GD-NICTA-whitepaper.pdf))

You can prove a system has no security flaws (it's much easier to do when the system is very very simple). And, yes, human interaction with a system that is proven secure can easily compromise the system via misuse.

But, I'm just asking if it's *fundamentally* possible to prove a current industry standard end-to-end system of secure data storage and transfer. I'm aware of security flaws due to misuse, I'm simply interested in whether there exist end-to-end (generate content, transfer content, store content) systems today which can be fundamentally *proven* with perfect usage.

---

I'm leaning toward the possibility that since most industry standard methods of sending and storing sensitive data is carried out on non-proven kernels, we cant prove any of our end-to-end systems currently. But that might not be true. Perhaps our encryption methods do enable us to secure data end-to-end, in a fundamentally proven way, regardless of whether we use a proven kernel to perform the encryption for storage and transfer.

Comment: Can you include a link to the micro kernel?

Comment: @NeilSmithline I appended an example. https://sel4.systems/Info/Docs/GD-NICTA-whitepaper.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There is no such system where you can exclude the human element. Software and hardware developers are humans so these systems you describe can and probably will have bugs. Also these systems are designed by humans and in the best case they include a risk analysis which is state of the art, but does not account for attacks nobody could think or attacks which are considered to costly in the foreseeable future.

Which means any system based on industry standards will have such bugs and will by design only protect you against most common risks. It will be fairly safe but not fully safe even after you somehow managed to exclude the human element *after* you've deployed the system.